# Golang AWS Custom Runtime Response Streaming

Tags: go, aws-lambda

I wanted to do custom response streaming on aws lambda but when return the second chunk it says RuntimeResponseSentState. please help me on this one.

Im currently following the instruction of aws link :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-walkthrough.html

My code

```
func main() {
    clientTrace := &httptrace.ClientTrace{
        GotConn: func(info httptrace.GotConnInfo) { log.Printf("conn was reused: %t", info.Reused) },
    }
    endpoint := os.Getenv("AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API")
    traceCtx := httptrace.WithClientTrace(context.Background(), clientTrace)

    // 1st request
    req1, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(traceCtx, http.MethodGet, "http://"+endpoint+"/2018-06-01/runtime/invocation/next", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    res1, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req1)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(res1)
    reqId := res1.Header.Get("Lambda-Runtime-Aws-Request-Id")
    os.Setenv("_X_AMZN_TRACE_ID", res1.Header.Get("Lambda-Runtime-Trace-Id"))

    b, err := io.ReadAll(res1.Body)
    fmt.Println(string(b))
    if _, err := io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, res1.Body); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    res1.Body.Close()
    // 2nd request
    req2, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(traceCtx, http.MethodPost, "http://"+endpoint+"/2018-06-01/runtime/invocation/"+reqId+"/response", bytes.NewBuffer([]byte("data : Hello")))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    req2.Header.Set("_X_AMZN_TRACE_ID", res1.Header.Get("Lambda-Runtime-Trace-Id"))
    req2.Header.Set("Lambda-Runtime-Function-Response-Mode", "streaming")
    req2.Header.Set("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked")
    req2.TransferEncoding = []string{"chunked"}
    res2, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req2)
    fmt.Println(res2)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if _, err := io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, res2.Body); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    b, _ = io.ReadAll(res2.Body)
    fmt.Println(string(b))
    res2.Body.Close()
    req3, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(traceCtx, http.MethodPost, "http://"+endpoint+"/2018-06-01/runtime/invocation/"+reqId+"/response", bytes.NewBuffer([]byte("data : Hello")))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    req3.Header.Set("_X_AMZN_TRACE_ID", res1.Header.Get("Lambda-Runtime-Trace-Id"))
    req3.Header.Set("Lambda-Runtime-Function-Response-Mode", "streaming")
    req3.TransferEncoding = []string{"chunked"}
    res3, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req3)
    fmt.Println(res3)
    b, _ = io.ReadAll(res3.Body)
    fmt.Println(string(b))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if _, err := io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, res3.Body); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    res3.Body.Close()
}
```

on aws console

```
2023/11/21 06:58:58 conn was reused: false
START RequestId: 789ebfcf-9a1b-4517-a9d5-7d408c4c1c45 Version: $LATEST
&{200 OK 200 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Content-Length:[49] Content-Type:[application/json] Date:[Tue, 21 Nov 2023 06:58:58 GMT] Lambda-Runtime-Aws-Request-Id:[789ebfcf-9a1b-4517-a9d5-7d408c4c1c45] Lambda-Runtime-Deadline-Ms:[1700549945351] Lambda-Runtime-Invoked-Function-Arn:[arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:130250231763:function:myFunction2] Lambda-Runtime-Trace-Id:[Root=1-655c5532-4acef3f33a57d61a7c4bcc0c;Parent=515fefae0cd6bee6;Sampled=0;Lineage=f35aca94:0]] 0xc000076300 49 [] false false map[] 0xc0000a8000 <nil>}
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3"
}
2023/11/21 06:58:58 conn was reused: true
&{202 Accepted 202 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Content-Length:[16] Content-Type:[application/json] Date:[Tue, 21 Nov 2023 06:58:58 GMT]] 0xc00010a080 16 [] false false map[] 0xc0000a8200 <nil>}
2023/11/21 06:58:58 conn was reused: true
&{403 Forbidden 403 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Content-Length:[184] Content-Type:[application/json] Date:[Tue, 21 Nov 2023 06:58:58 GMT]] 0xc00010a140 184 [] false false map[] 0xc000110200 <nil>}
{
  "errorMessage": "State transition from RuntimeResponseSentState to InvocationResponse failed for runtime. Error: State transition is not allowed",
  "errorType": "InvalidStateTransition"
}
RequestId: 789ebfcf-9a1b-4517-a9d5-7d408c4c1c45 Error: Runtime exited without providing a reason
Runtime.ExitError
```

I have tried to set transcoding in the header and in the code but no luck is there anything im missing also the aws custom runtime api is it http request or is it socket connection?

Comment: So after hours of banging my head against a wall i was able to finally find an answer to it. 
The problem was its not about the runtime api there was one missing component to it aws-web-adabter. Yes you can do it on the method mentioned above but its an uphill battle also it seems like you cant do a chunked request to a server atleast i cant find one. 

the saving grace was this : https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-web-adapter/tree/main/examples 

im not qualified to write an explanation myself i let the documentation do it. 
but im planning to write some example code .